# Jmeter - View Results In Table and View Results In Tree differ

Tags: jmeter

I am using the View Results in Table and View Results In Tree to view some results of a test.
My thread group has a number of users = 20; Rump up period =1; Loop=1000; This is a request to send the coordinates to server. After running these results differ. In View Results in Table displays error statuses:

[image]
But in View Results In Tree the result is successful, without errors:

[image]
What does it mean?

Comment: Please add some code for batter understanding of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the view "Results in Tree" is that it doesnt show all Samples. It just shows the latest 500 sampels

From the User's Manual...

> Starting with version 3.2 the number of entries in the View is restricted to the 
>   value of the property view.results.tree.max_results which defaults to 500 entries. The old behaviour can be restored by setting the property to 0. Beware, that this might consume a lot of memory.

So the last 500 entires from your table should match with the tree. For more information you might wanna check [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

You'll have to restart JMeter for it to apply the new setting

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Changelog for version 3.2](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

> Starting with JMeter version 3.2 the number of results in View Results Tree is limited by default to 500 entries. If you want more entries, you have to set the property view.results.tree.max_results to a higher value, or to 0, if you don't want to impose any limit. You can set the property in bin/user.properties. More info might be found [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree).

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (it lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   view.results.tree.max_results=0
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up

This way you will "tell" View Results Tree listener to show all the samplers (be aware that JMeter can fail to display 20 000 samplers in the View Results Tree listener)

---

Out of topic, but still important:

1. As per [View Results Tree listener documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

   > View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.
2. As far as I can see, you are running your test in GUI mode. Please don't, JMeter GUI should be used for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to test execution you should [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode).